# как мне сделать запрос http в python так как делается это через curl?

Tags: python, http, curl, requests

Как мне сделать запрос http в python так как делается через curl?

Вот как я задаю запрос через curl:

```
curl "https://www.olx.kz/ajax/misc/contact/phone/gs9Td/?pt=a9cdba69618837f749b5832b157bfa75902fdd70ccb1c1089d9017aee81506ed43adab49b662462cba83750bedfc91e4b9abcecb55bde2e92b63b65b45709c75" -H "cookie: mobile_default=desktop; dfp_segment_test_v3=89; dfp_segment_test=91; dfp_segment_test_v4=59; used_adblock=adblock_disabled; cto_lwid=e9b7dbf1-c9f9-498c-af3f-b1cc8fcc80f3; ldTd=true; _ga=GA1.2.896938926.1546742309; _gid=GA1.2.544627914.1546742309; dfp_user_id=d88a7fc8-d350-f71a-f6ff-a0a7af00a3be-ver2; _abck=A6D4DDA2446335E7556F6B6103F214FC57F5D4153A5D0000586A315C5FC06729~0~QqF1xuIw+12UKw1yJVTwOWVh3PjomkvgjBiPpecj990=~-1~-1; __utmc=16996198; __utmz=16996198.1546742311.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)^|utmccn=(direct)^|utmcmd=(none); __gads=ID=a71b5b7e3dee6947:T=1546742363:S=ALNI_Man9RWA-pKhgSg5h8hq6-fnXkGwLA; newrelicInited=0; cookieBarSeen=true; last_locations=1-0-0-^%^D0^%^90^%^D0^%^BB^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^B0^%^D1^%^82^%^D1^%^8B-^%^D0^%^90^%^D0^%^BB^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^B0^%^D1^%^82^%^D0^%^B8^%^D0^%^BD^%^D1^%^81^%^D0^%^BA^%^D0^%^B0^%^D1^%^8F+^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^B1^%^D0^%^BB^%^D0^%^B0^%^D1^%^81^%^D1^%^82^%^D1^%^8C-alma^%^3Aata; searchFavTooltip=1; lister_lifecycle=1546743641; bm_sz=2ECDFBC69F17DAF8C6F0250C438ED704~QAAQJtT1V28MA85mAQAAStBgImOJZduU1WNEl+JTC5Yv4d0Odxe7cNKG2MGjWNXBswPmrlBCzdxcAM0FEpicwr1uBED5oi9krg7FvD3h5cRkpcpd5Ud1qPJ43BFK7fZx3Q4qT6HYkq9Tljpbw4p4+XM6yCDQA7ovd3Y8WEDhmh9leviKtgJxG5mTki3ZxXY=; PHPSESSID=4c7c43c025d78dd7ca46bb3a7c22e0bbff2fc153; new_dfp_segment_dfp_user_id_d88a7fc8-d350-f71a-f6ff-a0a7af00a3be-ver2=^%^5B^%^5D; dfp_segment=^%^5B^%^5D; pt=a23d7f2ab302eb37e9d732a9e1797c614a72caa7df3eae49bc62edbbf751212818a4f1f96a677fd26ce1ca2ccdc6481afe7f320de0fe30420cb2c51de0febbf4; pvps=1; from_detail=1; __utma=16996198.896938926.1546742309.1546775001.1546777993.4; __utmt=1; avppv=1; avps=1; onap=16821069c97x7248cff7-4-168231e277cx3492199a-6-1546780281; _gat_clientNinja=1; __utmb=16996198.3.8.1546778480614" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" -H "accept: */*" -H "referer: https://www.olx.kz/obyavlenie/prodam-kompyuter-IDgs9Td.html" -H "authority: www.olx.kz" -H "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest" --compressed
```

как мне его же задать на python3, вот как я пытаюсь но не выходит:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.olx.kz/obyavlenie/prodam-kompyuter-IDgs9Td.html#7dead2828a'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',

           'cookie': 'mobile_default=desktop; dfp_segment_test_v3=89; dfp_segment_test=91; dfp_segment_test_v4=59; used_adblock=adblock_disabled; cto_lwid=e9b7dbf1-c9f9-498c-af3f-b1cc8fcc80f3; ldTd=true; _ga=GA1.2.896938926.1546742309; _gid=GA1.2.544627914.1546742309; dfp_user_id=d88a7fc8-d350-f71a-f6ff-a0a7af00a3be-ver2; _abck=A6D4DDA2446335E7556F6B6103F214FC57F5D4153A5D0000586A315C5FC06729~0~QqF1xuIw+12UKw1yJVTwOWVh3PjomkvgjBiPpecj990=~-1~-1; __utmc=16996198; __utmz=16996198.1546742311.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __gads=ID=a71b5b7e3dee6947:T=1546742363:S=ALNI_Man9RWA-pKhgSg5h8hq6-fnXkGwLA; newrelicInited=0; cookieBarSeen=true; last_locations=1-0-0-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-alma%3Aata; searchFavTooltip=1; lister_lifecycle=1546743641; bm_sz=2ECDFBC69F17DAF8C6F0250C438ED704~QAAQJtT1V28MA85mAQAAStBgImOJZduU1WNEl+JTC5Yv4d0Odxe7cNKG2MGjWNXBswPmrlBCzdxcAM0FEpicwr1uBED5oi9krg7FvD3h5cRkpcpd5Ud1qPJ43BFK7fZx3Q4qT6HYkq9Tljpbw4p4+XM6yCDQA7ovd3Y8WEDhmh9leviKtgJxG5mTki3ZxXY=; PHPSESSID=4c7c43c025d78dd7ca46bb3a7c22e0bbff2fc153; new_dfp_segment_dfp_user_id_d88a7fc8-d350-f71a-f6ff-a0a7af00a3be-ver2=%5B%5D; dfp_segment=%5B%5D; pt=a23d7f2ab302eb37e9d732a9e1797c614a72caa7df3eae49bc62edbbf751212818a4f1f96a677fd26ce1ca2ccdc6481afe7f320de0fe30420cb2c51de0febbf4; pvps=1; from_detail=1; _gat_clientNinja=1; __utma=16996198.896938926.1546742309.1546764948.1546775001.3; __utmt=1; onap=16821069c97x7248cff7-3-16822f96f11x6a5fb9b9-5-1546776810; __utmb=16996198.3.8.1546775009914',
           'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'https://www.olx.kz/obyavlenie/prodam-kompyuter-IDgs9Td.html',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}

response = requests.get(url,  headers=headers)

fixtures = response.json()
print(fixtures)
```

Вот такие вот ошибки выводит

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HTTP.py", line 16, in <module>
    fixtures = response.json()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Ошибка понятная. Т.к. запрос возвращает 'НЕ JSON', возникает ошибка преобразования ответа в JSON. (проверьте, что выдаст 'print (response.text')).

Comment: И с заголовком "'Host': 'www.whoscored.com'" сервер возвращает 400 - Bad Request

Comment: Зачем у вас `'Host': 'www.whoscored.com'`? В вашем curl такого нет

Comment: Кстати, да - запросы-то (конкретно URL'ы) разные. Тот, который в curl - возвращает JSON, а тот, который в программе - HTML (если из заголовков `'Host': 'www.whoscored.com'` убрать).